# Easy way to Highlight active link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I highlight active link in the following scenario?

I gave `.spcusr:hover, .spcusr:active{color:#adsder;}`

In this situation hover property works but active property doesn't work as its not a static link. Is there anyway that I can show different color to active span?? thnaks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true,
            navigation: true
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.showim = function(src) {
            $("#divcont").html(src);
        };
    });
</script>
<h3>
    <a href="#" style="height:200px;">
        <img src="unitedstates.jpg" width="100%" alt=""/>
    </a>
</h3>
<div>
    <span class="spcusr" onclick="showim('<h1>This is active now</h1>');">CLICK ME</span>
    <span class="spcusr" onclick="showim('<h1>This is active now</h1>');">CLICK ME</span>
    <span class="spcusr" onclick="showim('<h1>This is active now</h1>');">CLICK ME</span>
</div>
<div id="divcont"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/4T5s9/)**</kbd>

```
.active {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
  $('.spcusr').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.spcusr').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

and of course you could set active class for currently active span in HTML

```
<span class="spcusr active" onclick="showim('<h1>This is active now</h1>');">CLICK ME</span>
<span class="spcusr" onclick="showim('<h1>This is active now</h1>');">CLICK ME</span>
<span class="spcusr" onclick="showim('<h1>This is active now</h1>');">CLICK ME</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with CSS so use jquery.

Create a separate active class and add it when click function hits.

```
$('.spcusr').click(function () {        
     $('.spcusr').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');     
});
```

**DEMO**

Comment: Thanks Sowmya, I just checked your blog, found your email address and shooted you an email. Can you please have a look at it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**css**

```
.active{color:#cdcdcd}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.spcusr').click(function() {
    $('.spcusr').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

as per your current markup and js:

```
onclick="showim('<h1>This is active now</h1>', this);"
//---------------------------------------------^^^^---pass current el here

$(document).ready(function () {
   window.showim = function(src, el) { //<----get it here
       $(el).addClass('active').siblings('.spcusr').removeClass('.active');
       $("#divcont").html(src);
   };
});
```

in the css do this:

```
.spcusr:hover, 
.spcusr.active{
     color:#adsder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add separate class for active link using jquery